# Calculate current on tri-phase circuit with parallel resonance

Tags: current, ac, resonance, phasor

I'm struggling with the following circuit.

[image]

data are:

- E1=10V (three phase 120°)
- \$\omega\$=20 rad/s
- XC=-10
- R=10
- XL=10

About VGO I calculate the tri-phase voltage as

$$E=\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}=5,7735V$$

and

$$VGO=5,7735V\cdot3=17,321V$$

My problems comes calculating phasor of current I1 (current of E1), due to the parallel resonance that gave me \$\infty\$ as result...

Correct results are:

- \$VGO=17,321\$ V
- Phasor of \$I1=1,5+1,866025j\$ A

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Well, good. I suspected it. So could you shed some light on how to do that calcs? \$VGO\& is the Voltage of the whole circuit as shown in the image. T doesn't matter for this purpose is for another question about the circuit.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat That is the exercise my teacher gave me: it is all I have...

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct answers?